# Check and change date type

Tags: vba, date, types, format

I want to check if a content of a range of cells is formated as a date, and if it is, to change the current date type to date type `mm.dd.yyyy`. To do this I use the code below but it does not seem to work as it is changing the content of all cells in the range - not only to the one formatted as date.

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Sub FormatCurrency()    
    Dim Sh As Worksheet   
    Set Sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)    

    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In Sh.Range("R1:W300").Cells
        If Cell.NumberFormat = "Date" Then
            Cell.NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy"
        End If
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Well a `.NumberFormat = "Date"` does not exist because as you already know there are hundreds of *different* date formats, so there is no general `date` format. You need to check which number format the cell actually is. Therefore select one of these "date" cells and run `Debug.Print Selection.NumberFormat`. The result is in the immediate window then and this has to be used instead of `.NumberFormat = "Date"` then.

Comment: That worked fist fine. Thanx mate.